# Tokenize text you read from file according to rules

Tags: c, tokenize

I have an assignment to write a code, in which it should read a text file, then write an output file displaying the frequencies of each parameter in the code, i.e. "integers=2, keywords=13, identifiers=3..."

I have written a code,but the problem that I am facing, is that it always outputs all frequencies as 0's. As if the "integer++" and other incremental are not working.

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

   FILE *input; //file to read from
   FILE *output; //file to write to
   char *token=NULL;
   int keywords=0, identifier=0, integer=0, real=0, relationOperator=0, ArtOperator=0, lPar=0, rPar=0, semicolon=0, assign=0, comma=0, etc=0; 


   input = fopen("input.txt", "r"); //read from file
   if (input==NULL) {
             printf("I couldn't open input.txt for reading.\n");
             exit(0);
          }

   token=strstr(input, " "); //tokenize

        while (token!=NULL) //start of loop
        {
                if(token=="%s"){
                    if(token=="main"||"a"||"b"){ //if identifier
                        identifier++;
                    }
                    else{ //if keyword
                        keywords++; 
                    }
                  }
                else if(token=="%d"){ //if integer
                    integer++;
                  }
                else if(token=="%f"){ //if real number
                    real++;
                  }
                else if(token==">"||"<"){ //if relation operator
                    relationOperator++;
                  }
                else if(token=="+"||"-"||"*"||"/"){ //if arithmetic operator
                    ArtOperator++;
                  }
                else if(token=="("){ //if left parenthesis
                    lPar++;
                  }
                else if(token==")"){ //if right parenthesis
                    rPar++;
                  }
                else if(token==";"){ //if semicolon
                    semicolon++;
                  }
                else if(token=="="){ //if assignment operator
                    assign++;
                  }
                else if(token==","){ //if comma
                    comma++;
                  }
                else
                { //consider anything else as etc
                    etc++;
                  }
        token=strtok(NULL, " ");
   }//end of loop

   output = fopen("output.txt", "w"); //write to file

       if (output == NULL) {
             printf("I couldn't open output.txt for writing.\n");
             exit(0);
          }

         fprintf(output, "keywords = %d\n" ,keywords);
         fprintf(output, "identifiers = %d\n" ,identifier);
         fprintf(output, "integers = %d\n" ,integer);
         fprintf(output, "real numbers = %d\n" ,real);
         fprintf(output, "relation operators = %d\n" ,relationOperator);
         fprintf(output, "arithmetic operator = %d\n" ,ArtOperator);
         fprintf(output, "left parenthesis = %d\n" ,lPar);
         fprintf(output, "right parenthesis = %d\n" ,rPar);
         fprintf(output, "semicolons = %d\n" ,semicolon);
         fprintf(output, "assignment operators = %d\n" ,assign);
         fprintf(output, "commas = %d\n" ,comma);
         fprintf(output, "other characters = %d\n" ,etc);

         fclose(output); //close output file

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your loop needs to start by tokenizing the file and then needs to move, one by one, through the tokens. You aren't doing either right now.

Answer (score 2):

At the first glance of your code, I'm quite surprised it even compiles. Even if it does, 
the lines of form:

```
if(token=="+"||"-"||"*"||"/")
```

do not do what you think they do, you should rewrite that if statement as

```
if (*token == '+' || *token == '-' || ... || *token == '/')
```

token is a pointer, so you need to compare it's *value*, and use the correct syntax for a conditional statement, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading the file, you are not tokenizing, and you are comparing pointers to string literals, which is just plain wrong. Read up a bit on C and the standard library.